# JavaScript Date subtracting 4 hours

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a `JavaScript` function that compares 2 dates. I am trying to format the dates properly but the `Date` is subtracting 4 hours (presumably to compensate for GMT and EST), unnecessarily.

```
$.each(json.data, function(i, v) {              
        $.each(zoneObj, function(k, z) {  
            if (v.ptid == z.ptid) { 
                console.log(v.timeStamp);
                var d = new Date(v.timeStamp);
                console.log("datTime " + d);
```

**Result**
[image]

I see that `Date` is converting the `v.timeStamp` to Easter Standard but that isn't necessary. How do I disable this?

I need to use `Date` in order to take advantage of the `getMonth`, `getMinute`, etc. methods

Comment: Can you add bit more code around it, including very basic html? Maybe use some like jsfiddle.net so it's easier to help.

Comment: Ah, timezones. So, it's not **subtracting** 4 hours. It's the same moment in time, just different hours of the day depending which timezone. How are you using this date? Do you want to keep it in the client's timezone (EST)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: Please don't rely on images, not everyone can see them. Post the equivalent as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get UTC values of the standard *JS Date* object.

The functions are: `getUTCMilliseconds()`, `getUTCSeconds()`, `getUTCMinutes()`, `getUTCHours()`, `getUTCFullYear()`, `getUTCDay()` and `getUTCDate()`

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

But I would suggest you to use **moment.js**, which is far more powerful than standard *JS Date* and it is used by everyone.

Read more here: http://momentjs.com

Comment: Please do not reference w3schools, the site is full of errors. Reference either [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-constructor) or [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the methods for the Date object will use the local time which in your case is Eastern Standard Time.  If you want to use UTC, you need to specify those methods explicitly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date